# Looping through Variable URLs to retrieve HREF tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I'm very new to Python and think I'm 95% there on this one, but truly can't figure out what could be wrong while troubleshooting:

I'm looking to loop through 50,000 URLs, but the only thing changing in the URL is the final number

Essentially making links like this:

"https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/1"
"https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/2"
"https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/3"

My next thought was to make a working loop, just to ensure I can do it correctly:

```
for tag in range(0, 4):
    resp = ("https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/" + str(tag))
    print(resp)
```

Based on the output, this seems to create the exact links I want.

I then wanted to merge it with the code that seemed to scrape all HREF tags from a given list of URLs (final code below):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

profiles = []

for tag in range(0, 50000):
    resp = ("https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/" + str(tag))

urls = [
    resp
]

for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profile in soup.find('div', class_="profile-box").select('.half-column-left > p > a'):
        profile = profile.get('href')
        profiles.append(profile)

# print(profiles)

for p in profiles:
    if p.startswith('https'):
        print(tag, profile)
```

My confusion then stems from the fact it doesn't ALWAYS work.  If I change the range to (0, 7), I do see results.

I did some exploring and saw the URL below gives a 404 tag:

https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/8

I figured it should just skip broken links -- I added in an "else" statement, but my results still weren't correct.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to select a list of elements from an element that sometimes is `None`.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

profiles = []

for page in range(1, 50000):
    req = requests.get("https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Carmelo-Anthony/Summary/{page}".format(page = page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    element = soup.find('div', class_="profile-box")
    if element != None:
        for profile in element.select('.half-column-left > p > a'):
            profiles.append(profile.get('href'))

print(profiles)
```

Comment: This is working super well! There was one step further I'm trying to execute. Thought it would be easy, when I'm printing, I'm looking to print the ID (page) along with the links.  so I have it has print(page,p).  I'm noticing it's printing out the last page of the range for all of the links - rather than the link where the info was scraped; is there a small tweak to make that happen? will keep playing with it

Comment: You can do the following, import `from types import SimpleNamespace` at the header of your code, then when you're appending to the list add the elements like this: `profiles.append(SimpleNamespace(page = page, profile = profile.get('href')))` afterwards when you're printing the values of the array do it like this: `print('Page: ', item.page, ' Profile: ', item.profile)` this will give you the output that you are requesting.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out but no luck; I've added in the the import but when I append, I'm getting the "item" is not defined issue -- do I need to install something for this to work? @SaC-SeBaS

Comment: Update - I installed pretty-simple-namespace but still no luck.. a little confused